# Prevent Excel VBA autocomplete scrambling code

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm using Excel on a Mac (Catalina 10.15.8) and coding some functions and procedures in VBA (v 7.1).  I've found that recently the programming workbench is scrambling my lines of code as I enter them.  So for example, when I want to write:

```
Public function PPO2(Mix as String, Depth as Double) as Double
```

I get:

```
PublicfunctionPPO2(Mix as String,DepthasDouble) as double
```

The changes seem random, sometimes spacing is messed up, sometimes the cursor jumps back a few places so "PPO2 = PPO2 * 1.5" will come out as OPP2= PP2O*15.".  The changes are random but the problem happens with every line of code.  It seems, the larger the module, the more screwed up the lines are.  Even comment lines come out as garbage.

Has this happened to anyone else and is there a fix, or setting to turn off the autocomplete?

Comment: Same problem still happens even if typing in a blank VBA project of a newly opened Excel window instance?

Comment: Yes it does.  I started some functions from scratch, typing the first 20 or so lines was fine and then the automatic whitespace deleting kicked in.